# What is wrong with this twitter authentication

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have this code, but its not executing.

```
require_once('twitterOAuth.php');
session_start();

// The TwitterOAuth instance
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('consumerkey', 'consumersecret');
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://localhost/tweet/twitterOAuth.php');

// Saving them into the session
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// If everything goes well..
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){
    // Let's generate the URL and redirect
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: '. $url);
} else {
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
    die('Something wrong happened.');
}
```

Any reasons as to why?

Comment: Not even an error? It just does nothing?

Comment: But the  die('Something wrong happened.'); is fired

Comment: So it's executing. You'll want to `var_dump($twitteroauth->http_code);` just before the `die` and see what value is printed out.

Comment: Error: NULL Something wrong happened.

Answer (score 1):

**Twitter Oauth libraries and APIs do not work with localhost URLs.
You have to register your application with Twitter against a real URL and not localhost URLs.**

You should probably use some hosting service like Bluehost and then register your application against a URL.There is apparently another way  [set up a virtual host](http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php) which i haven't tried personally. But you can give it a try. I am not very sure it works.

Comment: did u try it on virtual host or a shared hosting site ? Another thing just dont pick the code. You should specify which Oauth library you are using ?

Comment: Apparently, it seems you are using Jaisen Mathai's Twitter async library. If you are referring this library, you should follow these tutorials http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/ http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/  Good luck try it out